# i want to host my videos on serve rand stream

Tags: video-streaming, web-hosting

hi iwant to host my videos

hi iwant to host my videos on server like this website doing 
https://vid4up.site/embedvideo/15d7ddb4260d7d 
but i dont know what the technologies they use or how they do it

hi iwant to host my videos on server like this website doing 
https://vid4up.site/embedvideo/15d7ddb4260d7d 
but i dont know what the technologies they use or how they do it